# Filter Pinterest-style Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a Pinterest-style grid of images in columns that I want to filter. The images have 2 different heights, but the widths are all the same.

Problem is when the image following a small image loads, it floats right underneath the small image, creating an ugly gap after it.

For example, when you click on "Category 3" here: http://www.designlunatic.com/demos/isotope/
The last element gets stuck underneath the smallest one, when I would want it to go all the way to the left.

I've tried using isotope, shuffle.js, mixitup, etc. These all seem to be based on grids with different heights and widths, and create gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the layout mode to masonryHorizontal to see if that helps. IE:

```
$container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal'
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false,
    }
});
```

I've dealt with similar things like this in the past, and I hate to say it, but you may need to download the unminified isotope js and customize the positioning to achieve the effect you want.

Here is the documentation on layout modes which can be helpful when you have specific needs for your site. Usually the default 'masonry' is the best approach, but when you have issues like this it can be helpful to try some of the alternatives:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html

I have one other hack for you. Isotope uses absolute positioning based on how it understands the sizes and shapes and area to work with. What you can do to trick isotope is to add empty divs (basically items that have visibility:hidden in the styles). It can consume an empty area and cause something to break into a different position. Dynamic content such as social media feeds can make this solution impractical, though.